# Most efficient way to join a table onto another table with 2 separate join criteria for part of the data

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables(`Table1` and `Table2`) that I want to join, however, the join criteria differs depending on the data in the `Country` column of `Table1`.

For all Records with value 'UK' in `Country`  column I would like to join on  `JoinField1`, `JoinField2` and `JoinField3`.

For all records with  value 'USA' in the `Country` column I would like to join on `JoinField2`, `JoinField3` and `JoinField4`.

At the moment I am simply joining `Table2` twice onto `Table1` with the different join criteria's. However I would like to avoid this as `Table2` has several hundred million rows of data and my query is having issues running.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this join?
Please note I am using DB2 SQL and can not use functions in the query.

[image]

Comment: Normalise your data model.

Comment: I wish :). Not really possible at the company I work at.

Answer (score 0):

You can express this as:

```
select . . .
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.country = t1.country and
        t2.Joinfield2 = t1.Joinfield2 and
        t2.Joinfield3 = t1.Joinfield3 and
        ( (t2.country = 'UK' and t2.Joinfield1 = t1.Joinfield1) or
          (t2.country = 'USA' and t2.Joinfield4 = t1.Joinfield4) 
        );
```

I'm not sure if this will improve performance, because `or` can be a performance killer.  But indexes on `(country, joinfield2, joinfield3, joinfield1, joinfield4)` can help.

Comment: Thansk. Never used ORS in joins before. I guess I'll just have to do a basic performace test to see which method works better.